# Magento Products and Categories in the same page

Tags: magento2, category, products, sub-categories

I'm fairly new to magento, and i've been looking for this solution for a while...
Is it possible to show categories(ex : subcategories) and products on the same page ?

I didn't seem to find anything on stack and magento docs !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: the keyword you're looking for is "layered navigation"

Comment: i've been searching for it, and on my understanding , layered navigation is basically the filters that appear on the side of the category page? ex: colors, size, brand?